# Error in Upload large file in asp.net core 6 (HTTP Error 413.1 - Request Entity Too Large)

Tags: upload, asp.net-core-mvc, large-files

I created a project with ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app.

I want to upload a large file, but I get HTTP Error 413.1 - Request Entity Too Large.

Client code is:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">Sending File</label>
            <input type="file" name="uploadfile" multiple>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And server code is:

```
    //100MG
    //[RequestSizeLimit(102428800)]
    [RequestSizeLimit(52428800)]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile uploadfile, [FromServices] IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Film\\Csharp", uploadfile.FileName);

        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
        {
            uploadfile.CopyTo(stream);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("UploadFile");
    }
```

When I read the Microsoft document, it said, the following entries were added to the `web.config` file, but I could not find the `web.config` file. Can anyone help me?

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Asp.Net Core` projects are created without a `web.config` file by default, But you can add it by yourself.

[image]

After you create a `web.config` file, you can add code to configure the size of upload file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="xxxxxxxxxx" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

More details you can refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-6.0).