# How to handled HTTP Error 413.1 - Request Entity Too Large in .net 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-5

HTTP Error 413.1-Request Entity Too Large page pops up when the limit is exceeded.
I know there is a certain limit for file upload.
But I want to catch that exception from the controller post method .

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" />
 <button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>

 [HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles([Bind]Model model)
      {
      
          ///handled file size , format exception and also want to handled that HTTP Error 413.1. 
      
      }`
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73697461/error-in-upload-large-file-in-asp-net-core-6-http-error-413-1-request-entity

Comment: that post about how to increase upload file limit but I don't want to increase that . I just want to show error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to handle a generic HTTP error at application level you can setup a CustomError section in your web.config within the system.web section:

```
<system.web>
 <customErrors mode=On defaultRedirect=yourCustomErrorPage.aspx />
</system.rweb>
```

Everytime the blunder is appeared the client will be diverted to your custom blunder page. If you need a specialized page for each mistake you'll be able do something like:

```
<system.web>    
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="yourCustomErrorPage.aspx">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="PageNotFound.aspx" />
   </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Comment: There is no web.config in .net 5.0.  how can i handled that using start up.cs file. Also i don't want to add web.config for some reason .